# How to create cohesive Spatial Pixels from Spatial Points Dataset

Tags: r, polygon, raster, rasterize

I have a Spatial Point DF `spo` (covering an irregular shaped area of interest). The data are not on a regular grid due to crs transformation.

My goal is a raster with predefined resolution and extent of the area of interest ( more spatial point data are to be mapped on this master raster) .

Problems start when I

```
rasterize(spo, raster(ncol, nrow, extent, crs), spo$param)
```

I need to adjust `nrow`and `ncol` in a way so that I wont get moire patterns of NAs within my area of interest. I can't use a predefined (higher) resolution, since `rasterize` has no interpolation capabilities.

As a solution to this, I thought I might need some kind of Spatial Pixel DF `spi`, that covers my whole area of interest (just like *meuse.grid* in `library(raster); data(meuse.grid)`), and serves as a master grid. Then, I can use it to interpolate my data, e.g.

```
idw(param~1,spo,spi)
```

and by this, get full cover of my area of interest at my chosen resolution. 
But how can a SpatialPixelsDataFrame be produced from the point data?

So in my view, the question boils down to: How to produce *meuse.grid* from *meuse* dataset?

Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach here, so please let me know if more easily can achieved what I'm after, using a different way.

Comment: This would be easier to work on if you provided a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a polygon that defines the boundary of your region of interest, (which you should), then it is straight forward. One approach is to use the `polygrid` function from `geoR`, which itself is just a wrapper for `SpatialPoints`, `expand.grid` and `overlay`

Lets assume that you have a polygon that defines your region of interest called called ROI

In this case I will create one from meuse.grid

```
 data(meuse.grid)
 coordinates(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
 x <- chull(meuse.grid@coords)
 borders <- meuse.grid@coords[c(x,x[1]),]

 ROI <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(borders)), ID = 'border')))
```

In reality, to use `polygrid` you only need the coordinates of the polygon that define your region of interest.

To create 10-m grid covering the area of this ROI you can create a call to `polygrid`

```
# get the bounding box for ROI an convert to a list
bboxROI <- apply(bbox(ROI), 1, as.list)
# create a sequence from min(x) to max(x) in each dimension
seqs <- lapply(bboxROI, function(x) seq(x$min, x$max, by= 10))

# rename to xgrid and ygrid
names(seqs) <- c('xgrid','ygrid')

thegrid <- do.call(polygrid,c(seqs, borders = list(ROI@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords)))
```

Comment: I already feared that I had to have a vector outline of the area in question and this is a very elegant way to construct it without doing it by hand. Thanks